# How to delete multiple files from a Cisco router flash memory

Tags: cisco, ios

I have filled up my router's flash with voice files and folders and wanted to remove them. I there  a script that can delete all files in flash except for the IOS image?

Comment: What does the manual suggests in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

`delete flash:<file>` is the command here. Depending of how are named your files, you can either to use a joker :

```
Router#delete flash:*.bak
Delete filename [*.bak]? 
Delete flash:/test.bak? [confirm]y
Delete flash:/rhgreg.bak? [confirm]y
```

If this doesn't work, you could try to write a TCL script, but I won't be able to help here.

Last option, copy the IOS image to a ftp/tftp server and `delete /recursive flash:`